# Como crear matrices en Python

Tags: python, matrices

necesito ayuda para armar una matriz en python y que al imprimirla me quede algo de este estilo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres imprimir asteriscos o puntos en una formación? ¿O esos puntos representan lo que serían números y quieres guardarlos en una matriz para después operar con ellos? ¿Para qué lo necesitas? ¿Qué has intentado de momento?

Comment: Quiero imprimir (punto espacio punto). Tengo que hacer el Snake y me piden un tablero así

Comment: Pues puedes hacerlo mediante bucles (en cada iteración del bucle imprimes una línea, y para imprimir esa línea puedes hacer otro bucle que imprima cada punto y cada espacio), o bien creando una lista con los puntos y espacios a imprimir y usar `str.join()` para juntarlo todo en una sola cadena que pueda imprimirse con un solo print. Depende de qué se suponga que sabes (puesto que es una tarea académica y no deberías usar cosas que no sepas :-))

Answer (score 1):

Para declarar un arreglo o matriz en python, primero crea una variable donde almacenaras tu arreglo, luego asignale sus valores:

```
arreglo = ['valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3'];//etc...
```

Esto notablemente es un arreglo comun no una matriz 3x6 como necesitas. sin embargo he aqui el truco:

dentro del arreglo podemos tener otros arreglos, asi que intentemos lo siguiente:

```
matriz = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
```

vemos ya un parecido a lo que requieres, donde los valores dentro de cada arreglo pueden ser realmente cualquiera.

Ahora lo mas importante...

Y como accedo a estos valores??

En programación primero debes tener en cuenta que los arreglos TODOS, comienzan contando siempre desde la posición 0, es decir, si tenemos el siguiente arreglo:

```
arr = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
```

Para acceder a la letra D, podemos imprimir en pantalla el contenido de esta manera:

```
print(arr[3]);
```

Esto imprimira la letra D, como los arreglos empiezan desde la posición 0, entonces 0 seria A, 1 seria B, 2 seria C y 3 seria D, etc.

Ahora, para el caso de nuestra matriz, tenemos varios arreglos dentro de un arreglo, la forma en la que podemos acceder a el valor de cada matriz es **primero accediendo a la fila y luego accediendo a la columna**.

Donde las filas representan las horizontales de izquierda a derecha, y las columnas las verticales de arriba a abajo.

entonces intentemos acceder al numero 8 localizado en la siguiente matriz:

```
matriz = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,8,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
```

Para acceder al valor que contiene el numero **8** entonces primero identificamos **la fila** en la que esta alojada el numero 8 contando de arriba hacia abajo, y luego la **columna** en la que esta alojada de izquierda a derecha, vemos entonces dos cosas:

- El numero 8 se encuentra contando de arriba hacia abajo en la **primera fila** (1), ya tenemos el primer indice.
- El numero 8 se encuentra en la **segunda columna** de izquierda a derecha, entonces ya tenemos el segundo indice.

Ahora accedamos a ese valor imprimiendolo:

```
print(matriz[1][2]);
```

El resultado es el numero 8, como ultimo dato, los datos que puede almacenar un array es cualquiera, y en un mismo array o matriz puedes almacenar diferentes tipos de datos, los numeros colocados en la matriz fueron solo un ejemplo.

Comment: ok, y como puedo imprimirla para que me quede como puse arriba?
porque logro que me quede la fila ....... pero cuando quiero imprimirla completa no se como hacer, tanto las filas como las columnas, sin que me aparescan entre [ ]

Comment: Eso lo debes hacer con un ciclo, preferentemente el ciclo for, pero eso ya no corresponde a la pregunta que hiciste (la pregunta es solo como definirlo, mas no como iterarlo e imprimir sus valores), y para no extender tanto la respuesta, te recomiendo mejor que lo consultes externamente, no he encontrado ningun link que exactamente te explique como usar el ciclo for, pero es algo muy sencillo, deberas usar ciclos for anidados para recorrer primero las filas y luego las columnas, te recomiendo ver algun video de youtube para ello, ahi seguro encontraras estas estructuras llamadas bucles.

Answer (score 0):

si ya dispones de tus arreglos, puedes invocar a numpy (primero asegurate de tenerlo instalado) y podras pintar tu matriz. Por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

mi_matriz = np.array([["L", 1,"u", 2, 3, "c"], [4, 5, 6, "i", 7, 8], [9, 10, "a", 11, 12, 13]])

print(mi_matriz)
```

El resultado mostrado seria:

```
[['L' '1' 'u' '2' '3' 'c']
 ['4' '5' '6' 'i' '7' '8']
 ['9' '10' 'a' '11' '12' '13']]
```