# Como declarar una matriz en python cuyo tamaño depende de una variable?

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

necesito crear una matriz en Pyhton dentro de una funcion que en java se haria de la siguiente manera:

```
public void crearMatriz(int tamaño){
     boolean[][] mat = new boolean[tamaño][tamaño]
}
```

En python como se hace esto ? Gracias

Comment: Antes de responder cómo se hace necesito saber para qué, ya que la respuesta depende de eso. Si estás haciendo cálculo numérico matricial, lo suyo en python es usar numpy, que tiene su propia forma de crear matrices. Si es para otra cosa (o no quieres/puedes usar numpy) en python no hay matrices, sino listas (y listas de listas) que son dinámicas y no necesitas darles un tamaño de antemano puesto que puedes ir añadiendo elementos a ellas.

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es una implementacion de una matriz de adyacencia,entonces estoy haciendo una clase y en el constructor necesito recibir el tamaño de la matriz de adyacencia.

Comment: Si vas a trabajar con matrices de tamaño prefijado, al estilo java, quizás sea mejor que uses `numpy`, que es muy eficiente para hacer cálculos con ese tipo de matrices. No obstante, si lo que vas a guardar en la matriz de adyacencia es algo del estilo un 1 en el elemento `[i][j]` para indicar adyacencia entre `i` y `j` y ceros en el resto, un diccionario que use tuplas en las claves puede ser una estructura más eficiente en el uso de memoria (especialmente si la matriz es grande y tiene muchos ceros y pocos unos). Realmente depende mucho de tu experiencia con python

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque la pregunta no demuestra ninguna investigación ni esfuerzo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como crear matrices en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297053/como-crear-matrices-en-python)

Answer (score 2):

A ver, realmente depende de para que quieras usarlas, y de qué manera. Personalmente, `numpy` es muy potente para esto y trabaja de manera eficiente. Pero te dejo un par de maneras:

```
import numpy

def crearMatriz(tamaño):

  # Crear una matriz con numpy     
  np_matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(tamaño,tamaño))

  # Y para crear una matriz de la manera "pythonica":
  pyth_matrix= [[0 for x in range(v)] for y in range(tamaño)]
```

Comment: Pero por qué has mezclado código python con Java? Eso de `public void` y las llaves.... qué dentera :-)

Comment: Se me ha ido, excuse me @abulafia